# need help with my ER model

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need help in designing a database model for my company.

basically it is a trading company into industrial products. so we have sales,purchases,inventory,warehouses,employees,receivables,payables, etc. as main functions.

I would greatly appreciate someone's help or guidance on how to go about it.
i have made the following tables:-

**sales invoice**

```
invoice no(PK), 
salesmanid,
customer code,
customer name,
voucher type,
invoice date,
invoice amount,
warehouse id
```

**sales items**

```
invoice no,
itemcode,
sale qty,
sales price
```

**inventory items**

```
itemcode(PK),
item name,
qty in stock,
cost price
```

**customer list**

```
customer code(PK),
customer name,
customer address,
salesman id
```

i need help with defining proper keys and advise on adding/removing coloumns, etc.

Comment: Is there a design for the whole system?  A quick way to identify useful tables, relations, and keys is to sketch up sample input forms and sample reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best advice: If you have to ask how to design a receivables table, you probably shouldn't be writing the receivables system. I've designed enterprise systems with over a thousand tables and *I* wouldn't willingly tackle an accounting system. With most custom development the system you deliver defines the business process to some degree. Your way can be slightly different than the designers envisioned and still be better.

With accounting software, there is One Way It Should Be Done. Your absolute best case is "we didn't screw it up".

Inventory, on the other hand, is usually domain-specific enough that it warrants custom coding. So: Why one big text field for address? Don't you need to know what state they're in (maybe not)? Do you analyze shipments by zip code? Do they have a phone number you care about? Customer name is often separated into first and last (at a minimum).

You might want to hold off on the database design until you know exactly (or mostly) what you're going to do with the data. Mock up a few reports, and a fake email cmpaign. Sketch out some interface screens. Then you can come back to the DB with a clearer idea of what you need. It does you no good to create an overly generic design upfront, and then have to keep modifying it. Of all the things you can change in your application, the DB is probably the toughest, so I'd try to work out the kinks in other areas first.

Answer (score 0):

> sales,purchases,inventory,warehouses,employees,receivables,payables,
>   etc. as main functions

Sales, purchases, receivables, and payables (at the very least) are accounting functions. If anybody proposed designing our own accounting software instead of buying it, I'd fire them. Or at least poke them in the eye with a sharp stick.

Sometimes, there's something to be said for reinventing the wheel. But not this wheel.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. but the main problem with readymade softwares is either it's too complicated which increases our dependency on the software provider for support,training, etc. OR it's too simple that one feels the need for customization(which becomes expensive)

Comment: @user728009: Three things. 1) You might be right in your judgment of off-the-shelf accounting software. But you're asking for help with defining keys. If you can't do that yourself already, you don't have the skills to create an accounting system. 2) I've been in this business for 25 years, and consulted in over 800 companies, including several Fortune 500s. Not a single one of them thought it was a good idea to write their own accounting software. 3) 50% of businesses that suffer a catastrophic loss of accounting data survive less than 6 months. Don't write your own accounting software.

Comment: thanks for the note. well i am confused, what i really want is inventory control and analysis over inventory items, sales, purchases. i would appreciate if you can advise me. accounting can be managed with any standard program

Comment: @mmdel: Inventory control and reporting (but perhaps not analysis) is part of our accounting systems. Maybe it should be part of yours, too.